# Use Jackson JSON processor with USE_ANNOTATIONS set to false

Tags: android, json, jackson

I am using `Jackson 1.8.3` and it looks like in the `AnnotatedClass` annotations are still evaluated in "construct" or in "`constructWithoutSuperTypes`" because even with `USE_ANNOTATIONS` set to false the `resolveClassAnnotations` bypasses the settings. Can someone verify my findings? I am working on an Android project that is using Android SDK version 8 as the minimum.

In a similar post on the 17th of February `Jackson 1.8` was patched, but was never verified as functional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to discuss this on Jackson user or dev list; and perhaps file a bug report?

Comment: I have confirmation that there is a minor issue and will post back with the resolution soon.

Comment: Awesome. It would be shame if solution to the problem wrt annotations did not work.